# Expectation of a betting game involving generalized Catalan numbers

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients, catalan-numbers

I've recently become interested in a type of biased random walk. In the original context, the simplest problem I cannot answer is as follows:

> Suppose you enter a simple but lousy betting game. The price to enter
> is \$3, and a fair coin is flipped. If it lands heads you win \$4,
> otherwise you win nothing. So, each game either increases your wealth by
> \$1 or decreases it by \$3. If you begin with just \$3 and repeatedly
> enter the game until you can no longer pay the fee, what is the
> expected number of games you will play?

Actually, I'd like to be able to answer this question for any game where the cost is $m$, the prize is $m+1$, and we have any given amount of starting wealth $w$. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3772067/expected-number-of-coin-tosses-untill-number-of-head-exceeds-number-of-tails) similar question+answer shows that the expectation diverges when $m=1$ for any starting wealth.

Another way to phrase the question would be as a random walk. If you consider our position on the number line to be our total wealth after paying the fee, the case $m=w=1$ is a random walk from the origin that ends whenever the position becomes negative. The general case $m$ is a sort of random walk, but really it's more of a "stumble", since we either advance one step or reverse $m$ steps. I am interested in the expected length of these $m$-stumbles. Here is what I know so far:

The expected number of games, $g_{m,w}$, satisfies an easy recurrence relating your starting wealth:

$$ g_{m,w}  = 1 + \frac{1}{2}g_{m,w+1} + \frac{1}{2}g_{m,w-m}$$

Which I find has generating function:

$$\sum_{w \ge 0} g_{m,w}z^n = \left(\alpha_m - \frac{2z}{1-z}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1 - 2z + z^{m+1}}\right)z^{m}$$

where $\alpha_m = g_{m,m}$ represents the average length of an $m$-stumble from the origin. The $g$ terms are related to the [Fibonacci n-step numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fibonaccin-StepNumber.html) by $A_{w}\alpha_m - 2B_{w}$ where A is a partial sum of the first $w$ n-step numbers $\sum_{k \le w}F_{k}^{(n)}$, and B is a double convolution, i.e. the sum of the first $w-1$ partial sums $\sum\sum_{k < w}F^{(n)}_{k}$. The easiest way to find $g_{m,w}$ given some $g_{m,s}$ that I know of is to use the recurrence directly.

I have found the following double sum formula for general $\alpha_m$:

$$\alpha_m = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{m} k\binom{mn + n + k}{n} / 2^{mn + n + k}$$

which more-or-less follows from the definition of the Fuss-Catalan numbers. Each term represents the contribution to the expectation of games ending at flip number $(m+1)n+k$. The inner sum does not include the term $k=0$ because it is not possible to lose after flip numbers divisible by $m+1$. (After flip $n$ your total wealth must be congruent to $n+m \mod{(m+1)}$, since it increases by exactly $1$ or $-m \equiv +1 \mod{(m+1)}$ each flip, and it begins at $w = m \equiv -1 \mod{(m+1)}$, so if you haven't already lost your wealth must be at least $m$ meaning you are guaranteed to have enough to pay the fee for these games.)

I don't know how to evaluate this sum, but I do know at least one value and have good guesses for others. We know from the linked question $\alpha_1 = \infty$, but for $m > 1$, $\alpha_m$ converges. The one value I know is:

$$\alpha_2 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{3n+1}{n}/2^{3n+1} + 2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{3n+2}{n}/2^{3n+2} = 1 + \sqrt{5}$$

Which is the value Mathematica gives me. I don't how how it arrives at this value, but it appears correct and matches my simulations. Unfortunately, Mathematica chokes on $\alpha_3$ and higher. I guessed that $\alpha_m$ is the root of an $m$'th order polynomial, so $\alpha_2 = 1 + \sqrt{5} = (x^2 - 2x - 4)_{+}$, meaning $\alpha_2$ is the unique positive real root of $x^2 - 2x - 4 = 0$.

A value for $\alpha_3$ would answer the initial problem statement in this question. I find the following guesses match the value of my sum with very high accuracy, to at least 100 digits:

$$
\begin{align}
\alpha_3 &= (x^3 - 4x - 4)_{+} \\
\alpha_4 &= (3x^4 + 4x^3 - 8x^2 - 24x - 16)_{+} \\
\alpha_5 &= (2x^5 + 5x^4 - 20x^2 - 32x - 16)_{+}
\end{align}
$$

but even knowing these values I have no idea how to prove them, even for the apparently simple cases of $\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_3$. Does anyone know how to find $\alpha_3$ or general $\alpha_m$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna show that $\alpha_m$ is the (unique) solution of $\alpha^{m+1}=(\alpha-2)(\alpha+2)^m$ with $\alpha>2$.

My point of departure is your double sum, rewritten as $$\alpha_{m-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}k\cdot 2^{-k}G_{m,k}(2^{-m}),\qquad G_{m,k}(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{mn+k}{n}z^n.$$

> Since you're familiar with the [Fuss–Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuss%E2%80%93Catalan_number), let's recall that if $$F_{m,k}(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{k}{mn+k}\binom{mn+k}{n}z^n$$ and $F_m(z)=F_{m,1}(z)$, then $F_{m,k}(z)=\big(F_m(z)\big)^k$ and $F_m(z)=1+z\big(F_m(z)\big)^m$.

Now $G_{m,k}(z)$ can be expressed in terms of $F_m(z)$. We have $$G_{m,k}(z)=F_{m,k}(z)+\frac{mz}{k}F_{m,k}'(z)=\big(F_{m}(z)\big)^k R_m(z),$$ where $R_m(z)=1+mzF_m'(z)/F_m(z)$. On the other hand, $F_m'(z)=\big(F_m(z)\big)^m R_m(z)$ by taking the derivative of $F_m(z)=1+z\big(F_m(z)\big)^m$. Hence $$R_m(z)=1+\frac{mz}{F_m(z)}\frac{F_m(z)-1}{z}R_m(z);$$ solving this, we get $R_m(z)=F_m(z)/\big(m-(m-1)F_m(z)\big)$ and $$G_{m,k}(z)=\frac{\big(F_m(z)\big)^{k+1}}{m-(m-1)F_m(z)}.$$

---

Thus, $2^{-k}G_{m,k}(2^{-m})=2x_m^{k+1}/\big(m-2(m-1)x_m\big)$, where $x_m=F_m(2^{-m})/2\color{blue}{\in(1/2,1)}$ implied by $m-2(m-1)x_m>0$. And $x_m$ is the unique solution $x\in(1/2,1)$ of $$0=x^m-2x+1=(x-1)(x^{m-1}+\ldots+x-1).$$

Then $\beta_m=x_{m+1}$ is the unique solution $\beta>1/2$ of $\beta^m+\ldots+\beta=1$, and $$\alpha_m=\frac{2\beta_m\gamma_m}{1-m(2\beta_m-1)},\qquad\gamma_m=\sum_{k=1}^m k\beta_m^k.$$ Now $\beta_m\gamma_m=m\beta_m^{m+1}+\sum_{k=1}^m(k-1)\beta_m^k=m(2\beta_m-1)+\gamma_m-1$ gives $$\gamma_m=\frac{1-m(2\beta_m-1)}{1-\beta_m}\implies\alpha_m=\frac{2\beta_m}{1-\beta_m}\implies\beta_m=\frac{\alpha_m}{\alpha_m+2},$$ and if we put $\beta=\alpha/(\alpha+2)$ into $\beta^{m+1}=2\beta-1$, we get the claimed equation for $\alpha=\alpha_m$.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!

Comment: Could you explain the how you arrived at the relationship between $G$ and $F$ in more detail? I recall the quoted properties of $F_{m,k}$ and am satisfied with the relation $G_{m,k}(z) = F_{m,k}(z)+ mzF^\prime_{m,k}(z)/k$, but I wasn't able to show the one above.

Comment: @Brocellous: Done (edited the answer).